# Error al resta fechas y actualizar datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Aquí tengo la consulta

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
```

Quiero recorrer una tabla llamada ESCUELA, tomar de cada registro el campo fecha1 y restarla con la variable fec_act (fecha Actual), dejando el resultado en la variable wdias1 y expresados en días.

```
def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
    #query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela'
    record1 = self.tree.get_children()
    for row in record1:
        print(type(self.fecha1), repr(self.fecha1.get()))
        fec_act = datetime.today()
        fec_estu = datetime(strptime(self.fecha1.get()), '%d/%m/%Y')
        wdias1.set((fec_act - fec_estu).days)
```

Luego quiero ir actualizando el campo días de la tabla ESCUELA con el resultado arrojado

```
        query = 'UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ? WHERE dias1 = ?'
        parameters = (wdias1, )
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
```

Creo que es una simple función, pero no se si comprendo bien como trabaja python con sqlite3 y si mi código tiene sentido o esta muy errado, agradezco la orientación que me puedan dar.

Error:

```
<class 'tkinter.Entry'> ''

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File "index5.py", line 196, in actualizar_estudiantes
     fec_estu = datetime(strptime(self.fecha1.get()), '%d/%m/%Y')
   File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\_strptime.py", line 562, in _strptime_time
tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
   32\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
          raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
     ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

Agradezco su ayuda u orientación, Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda FJSevilla, <class 'tkinter.Entry'> <tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry5>

Comment: Si es un Entry, para obtener el texto debes hacer `self.fecha1.get()` no `str(self.fecha1)`. Si te sigue dando el error muestra que imprime `print(repr(self.fecha1.get()))`.

Comment: Dio error esto muestra el print =      <class 'tkinter.Entry'> ''

Comment: Al final del error aparece= ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', creo es que no esta tomando o leyendo la fecha de la tabla

Comment: la pagina me mando a actualizar la pregunta

Comment: me sigue dando la misma respuesta

Comment: Te está retornando una cadena vacía, aparentemente no tienes nada ingresado en el Entry cuando la función se ejcuta.

Comment: Como se puede resolver el problema, me puede dar una orientación

Comment: Habría que saber desde dónde y cuándo llamas a `actualizar_estudiantes` y si en ese momento el `Entry` `self.fecha1` tiene una fecha válida ingresada (que no la tiene, está vacío y habŕiaa que ver porqué). No obstante, dices: "...tomar de cada registro el campo fecha1 y restarla con la variable fec_act (fecha Actual)" ¿`self.fecha1` no debería ser en realidad la fecha obtenida de la BD mediante `row`?

Comment: ¿self.fecha1 no debería ser en realidad la fecha obtenida de la BD mediante row? – La realidad es que creo que estoy haciendo eso, porque entro al for y voy tomando en cada registro fecha1 par luego usarla para restar o no! Puedo mandar el código? no es tan largo

Comment: Puedes agregarlo a la pregunta, para usar la fecha de a BD tendrias que indizar sobre row para obtener laa fecha de cada fila, self.fecha1 es un Entry. De hecho iteras sobre las filas de la consulta pero no usas los datos para nada, no usas row... Por eso preguntaba.

Comment: creo entender lo que me explicas,  pero no se como hacerlo, no se como obtener la facha si no es como lo estoy haciendo

Comment: Si quieres obtener la fecha de cada fila de la tabla solo indiza sobre row, (fecha = row[indice]) el índice dependerá de la posición que la columna con la fecha ocupe en la tabla escuela de tu BD

Comment: gracias lo intentare asi, muchas gracias por la ayuda, saludos

Comment: Amigo un ultima pregunta, me puedes mandar un ejemplo de lo que me sugieres o mandarme a un link donde yo pueda ver un ejemplo de lectura de tabla y obtencion de datos para yo guiarme, estoy empezando y estoy bastante como puede ver desorientado o una pagina que me recomiendes a seguir, saludos y gracias por tu paciencia